# Can use both of react-router and react-navigation in React-Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm using `react-navigation` and `redux` in my project, and I had a question that whether should I import `react-router` after reading `Redux Document` [Usage with React Router](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/UsageWithReactRouter.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use both but no need to do this. It's better to use one navigation system. I suggest you to use react-navigation which can be fully integrated with redux.